# Flex 4: DataGrid doesn't intercept event dispatched from custom itemRender

Tags: events, datagrid, flex4, renderer, dispatch

I'm trying to intercept an event dispatched by my custom renderer in this way:

```
this.owner.dispatchEvent(new ResultEvent("eventName",true,false,parameter));
```

Here is my grid:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="calendarGrid">
        <mx:columns>
          <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="header"
                             id="h"
                             sortable="false"
                             itemRenderer="myRenderer"/>
        </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

and here is how I add eventlistener to my grid:

```
calendarGrid.addEventListener("eventName", handlerFunction);
```

handlerFunction is never called.
Please help...

SORRY MY FAULT...
addEventListener was in the creationComplete function which (I don't know why) never fires.
Now it works!

Comment: Does `calendarGrid` ever dispatch the "eventName" event? What event are you listening for?

Comment: Looks like you answered your own question.  You should add this as an answer and mark it answered so others will benefit from your solution.

Answer (score 0):

SORRY MY FAULT... addEventListener was in the creationComplete function wich (I don't know why) never fires. Now works!